# 106 Pixel Adalight Config

Tags: arduino, processing, pixel

I'm trying to set up a 106 pixel Adalight configuration around the TV in my family room.  Anyway, the Processing IDE is telling me there's an unexpected token: { in this line

```
  {0,1,0}, {0,2,0}, {0,3,0}, {0,4,0}, {0,5,0}, {0,6,0}, {0,7,0}, {0,8,0}, {0,9,0}, {0,10,0}, // Top edge
```

I can't find where there's an out of place {

Here's the entire section of code
http://pastebin.com/ZxiWbTu9 (It wasn't all going in as code, sorry.)

Comment: Please give us the whole instruction, from the variable to the semicolon.

Comment: Alright, the entire section is posted in a pastebin link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma at the end of the previous line, and on lines 7 and 9.